# Replace multiple parts of a string based on character location if the cell starts with certain characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that could be any number of lines containing different values each time. I would like to find the lines that begin with "820" and replace the 3 character with a "2", the 21-32 characters with "000000000000" and the 45th character with a "0".

Lines in the A column.

627000000000016579615        0000005000TESTING        TESTING CR              0000000000000003
820000000300183044060000000050000000000050001000000000                         000000000000001
9000001000001000000030018304406000000005000000000005000

What I need (I've bolded the changes):

627000000000016579615        0000005000TESTING        TESTING CR              0000000000000003
82**2**000000300183044060**000000000000**00000005000**0**000000000                         000000000000001
9000001000001000000030018304406000000005000000000005000

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you run into trouble? Please include that in your question.

Comment: You need string manipulation functions like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function  Then try something and show us the code you tried

Comment: Please format your question, and make sure to post what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without VBA if you want.

Put this in another column, change reference if needed (is looking at A1) and copy it down:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,3)="820",REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,3,1,"2"),21,12,REPT(0,12)),45,1,"0"),A1)
```

Basically it does 3 replaces.

- First replaces character 3 with the 2.
- Then uses the first replaced string with the 12 zeros from character 21. The `REPT` simply repeats a zero 12 times.
- Then finally replaces the second replaced string at character 45 with a 0
- If the cell doesn't start with "820" then it just returns that cell value which you can see at the end of the formula. If you just want it to be blank then replace the last `A1` with `""`